# WD Passport Ultra Write-Protected

Tags: external-hard-drive, write-protect

When I tried to deep format my `WD Passport Ultra` using `Data Lifeguard Diagnostic for Windows` it went through but when it got time to allocate the disk for some reasons I can't.

What is happening is after searching for new drives (`Rescan Disks`) in `Disk Managment` on `Windows 10` my `WD Passport Ultra` appears as unallocated disk. However sometimes I can right click on the disk and click `Initialize Disk` and sometime I can not. In both ways I always get the same error message `The device is not ready`

I have downloaded a third-party software called `EaseUS Partition Master` and when I try to create/allocate the disk I get the error that this hard disk is write only protected - `The operation did not complete because the media is write-protected.`
However I even tried to remove write-only via `CMD` but I can not to do so because the drive isn't in the list.

I think I have done all of the possible things I could've which I have found on the internet and I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: The drive is probably defective.

Comment: Is there a way to fix the drive?

Comment: Probably not but check with the manufacturer anyway.